# Vivitar Lens compatibility with Minolta Maxxum 5

Tags: lens-mount, minolta, vivitar

Will a Vivitar `Series One Zoom 28-300mm` lens work correctly on a Minolta `Maxxum 5` Digital Camera?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y)

Comment: No, it is misleading here: The Maxxum 5D is an A mount camera, and the Series 1 28-300mm exists as an A mount version. No cross-mount adapting needed. However, there can be firmware issues with certain combinations of A mount hardware.

Answer (score 3):

Vivitar is a third-party lens maker that can make a lens in a variety of camera mounts, so there's no way anyone can answer your question without being able to see the specific lens you're talking about.  I'd suggest looking through [a visual guide to lens mounts](http://rick_oleson.tripod.com/index-99.html) to see if the Vivitar uses the mount for the Minolta AF or Sony A-mount systems (the mount the Maxxum 5 uses).

This is Minolta's autofocus mount. The manual-focus SLR mounts, (Minolta MD and Minolta MC) cannot be used directly on the Maxxum 5.

Answer (score 1):

Very briefly, lenses are generally only compatible with one particular mount, so if you want a lens for a Minolta Maxxum 5D, then you need to buy an A-mount lens, which is the name of the mount used on that camera. Minolta developed the A-mount for their interchangeable-lens autofocus cameras, and Sony also uses the A-mount. (Be aware though that Sony also has interchangeable-lens cameras that use another mount called the E-mount, and E-mount lenses are not compatible with A-mount camera bodies. Also, don't confuse A-mount with Sony Alpha (α), the brand name that Sony uses to refer to its range of interchangeable-lens cameras as a whole, encompassing both A-mount and E-mount.)

You will find A-mount lenses from Sony and Minolta and also third-party lens manufacturers such as Sigma, Tamron and Tokina amongst others.